# Return multiple lists in mapply

Tags: r, mapply

I have a function which I am applying across a list of data frames or matrices (df) using mapply.  The function outputs four different types of data frames (ex. a:d) based on some criteria of transformation of the original data frame, but I am having issues as function will only let me output one.  I have tried to collate them into a list, but when I run a simplified function, I get this.

```
df1<-matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=10, ncol=10)
df2<-df1
df<-list(df1, df2)

func<-function (x) {
  a<-x*1
  b<-x*2
  c<-x*3
  d<-x*4
  return(list(a,b,c,d))
}

finalresult<-mapply(func, x=df)

str(finalresult)

List of 8
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -3.211 -0.121 -0.2 0.491 1.118 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -6.422 -0.242 -0.4 0.982 2.235 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -9.633 -0.362 -0.6 1.473 3.353 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -12.844 -0.483 -0.8 1.964 4.471 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -3.211 -0.121 -0.2 0.491 1.118 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -6.422 -0.242 -0.4 0.982 2.235 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -9.633 -0.362 -0.6 1.473 3.353 ...
 $ : num [1:10, 1:10] -12.844 -0.483 -0.8 1.964 4.471 ...
 - attr(*, "dim")= int [1:2] 4 2
```

In this case you can see it is just giving me the list of the four output data frames (a:d) from df1 and then appends the next set of outputs from df2 right after.  I want to have an output where each data frame transformation is put in a list where I can access it by category (ex. finalresults$a).  Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,
-Chelsea

Comment: Set `SIMPLIFY = FALSE` in `mapply`.

Comment: Thank you for the response!  I'm getting an error when I run this with SIMPLIFY=FALSE: SI: Error in function (x)  : unused argument(s) (SIMPLY = dots[[2]][[1]])

Comment: you need to use `SIMPLIFY=FALSE`, not `SIMPLY=FALSE` (!)

Comment: Apologies- terrible typing error.  This result does give me a list, but it is per input data frame (list of a:d for df1, list of a:d for df2).  What I want is a list per output data frame (list of transformed df1:df2 for a, list of transformed df1:df2 for b, etc.).

Comment: You will have to do that post festum. FWIW, `Error in function (x) : unused argument(s)` always means you specified an argument that does not exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about:

Use `mapply` but don't simplify.

```
result1 <- mapply(func, x=df, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Iterate over the indices (this assumes both lists in the result are the same length); for each index `i`, use `lapply` to pull out the `i`th element of each list in `result1`.

```
 result2 <- lapply(seq_along(result1[[1]]),
              function(i) lapply(result1,"[[",i))
```

I tried a little bit to shorten/obfuscate this still further (i.e. remove the need to define an anonymous function), but with nested `lapply`s I can't quite figure out how to make it work.

Comment: This works, and it runs quickly through my output.  Thanks for the solution!

Comment: to be fair, I think @HansRoggeman's answer is essentially the same as mine; mine looks simpler because (1) it's slightly better formatted; (2) he included the data-generation code; (3) he put in some extra functionality to name the results.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that gives what you want. It basically names your list returns and then aggregates by the name.

```
df1<-matrix(rnorm(10), nrow=10, ncol=10)
df2<-df1
df<-list(df1, df2)
namesToReferTo = letters[1:4]
func<-function (x) {
  a<-x*1; b<-x*2; c<-x*3; d<-x*4
  retList = list(a,b,c,d)
  names(retList)=namesToReferTo
  return(retList)
}
finalresult = lapply(namesToReferTo, function(y) { lapply(lapply(df,func), function(x) { x[[y]] }) } )
# alternatively: finalresult = lapply(namesToReferTo, function(y) { Map(function(x) { return(x[[y]])} , lapply(df,func)) } )
names(finalresult) = namesToReferTo
str(finalresult)
finalresult$b
```